# Live555 SDP received but no data stream received

Tags: rtsp, windows-firewall, live555, rtsp-client

I tried testH264VideoFramer. And It work fine locally(rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/testStream). Tested with VLC Player and testRTSPClient

However, If I try to connect remotely. Only SDP data received but no data stream received

```
Got a SDP description: v=0
o=- 1447008154324154 1 IN IP4 192.168.126.1
s=Session streamed by "testH264VideoStreamer"
i=test.264
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.08.07
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 * 192.168.126.1
a=rtcp-unicast: reflection
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:Session streamed by "testH264VideoStreamer"
a=x-qt-text-inf:test.264
m=video 18888 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 232.122.81.169/255
b=AS:500
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=control:track1

......
Start playing session
..... And then nothing coming out
```

Is it a router problem or a firewall problem? I've allowed my program passing firewall for UDP/TCP in both local/public network

Comment: Just use wireshark to check what's going on, check if other RTSP commands, like SETUP and PLAY are coming through and if actual RTP playback starts. You may need to add port forwarding for UDP packets on your router.

Comment: Yeah, i used wireshark. It's actually a router problem. I am now using unicast. I'll self-answer my question soon.

Comment: The SDP is sent with RTCP using TCP so gets through firewalls in most cases.
The actual data you're sending is probably sent via UDP (in fact it definitely is as your using a multicast address) so is more likely to be blocked by firewalls, routers etc.
If you run the client (openRTSP or testRTSPClient) with -t or -T flags you should find it works. There's also an option in the VLC settings, search for rtsp in there and its in the rtp/rtsp demuxers panel.

Answer (score 0):

1- Make Sure that any Anti-Virus on your device is disabled .
2- Make Sure that there is **ONLY ONE INSTANCE** of **VLC** is running.
To check on this do the following :
a- Open task manager 
b- End VLC task 
c- Run VLC again 
d- open"show hidden icon" in taskbar to check that one instance of VLC is running and stream it will work